# iOS - Constraint to UIImage with centrally aligned UILabel's text

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have `UITableViewCell` that has a UIlabel aligned center I'm setting image in default imageView property of the `UITableViewCell` but since text is aligned center there is a gap between text and the image.

I want image then little space then text all center to `UITableViewCell` I have tried following code,

```
    cell.imageView?.image = image
    cell.imageView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.imageView?.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    let rect: CGRect = label.textRect(forBounds: label.bounds, limitedToNumberOfLines: 1)
    cell.imageView?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.leadingAnchor, constant: rect.origin.x - padding).isActive = true
```

That works for me but when I switch device from iPhone 11 Max Pro to iPhone 8 image overlaps the text because `label.textRect` always brings the same text irrespective of screen size

I have also tried using range of the first later and using it's rect but same problem of not being changed per screen size.

Can this be achieved without putting custom `UIImageView` in `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Never ever _measure_ anything and use it in autolayout, like your `rect = label.textRect`. The whole point is that you let _auto layout_ do all the measuring.

Comment: @matt I agree but then default uiimageview in UITableViewCell will always stick to left (leading of the cell) and uilabel's text is aligned center so only way to achieve this is custom UITableViewCell?

Comment: Are you trying to center label + imageView as a whole with some spacing between them?

Comment: @rs7 Yes, that's the desire

Comment: @ArunKumar I'm not sure what the issue is there; if you're going to use autolayout to lay out your cell, you _must_ use a custom cell class. That's like four lines of simple code, so there can be no objection surely.

Comment: Yes, I do have custom classes and it's pretty easy to use but I just wanted to know if this is achievable with default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a stackView that you center inside your cell and add your imageView and your label as arranged subViews. Note that you would need to create a custom cell.

1. Create your stackView:

   ```
   let stackView: UIStackView = {
       let stackView = UIStackView()
       stackView.axis = .horizontal
       stackView.alignment = .center
       stackView.distribution = .fill
       stackView.spacing = 10 // You can set the spacing accordingly
       return stackView
   }()
   ```
2. Layout as follows:

   ```
   contentView.addSubview(stackView)

   // Swap these two lines if instead you want label then image
   stackView.addArrangedSubview(image)
   stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)

   // StackView
   stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
   stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
   ```

Comment: I have achieved it using stack view in my storyboard I just want to confirm if this is achievable with the approach I took

Comment: I'm going ahead with your approach keeping default approach aside. Thanks

Comment: One of the problems I'm having with the code is content of label is going out of the cell. if I give leading and trailing to stack view then it stays inside but then it's not center

Comment: It would probably best to open a new thread for that, but basically, you could set your stackView's edge constraints to be greater or equal/less or equal than the cell's edges. Additionally, you can set automatically adjust font size for your label and/or set the numberOfLines to 0 so that the label can have an unlimited amount of lines.

Comment: Sure I will give it shot otherwise will open new thread thanks for all the help